# Why is the label attribute not working for option tags inside an iFrame in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe

I'm trying to make a HTML editor and put the result in an `<iframe>`. Everything work fine except the `label` attribute of `<option>` tags, which is completely ignored. I'm using latest version of Chrome (113.0.5672.127)

Example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="a">
        <option value="a" label="a">aaaaaa</option>
        <option value="b" label="b">bbbbbb</option>
        <option value="c" label="c"></option>
        <option value="d" label="d"></option>
    </select>
    <iframe id="frm"></iframe>
    <script>
        let str = document.getElementById('a').outerHTML;
        let frm = document.getElementById('frm');
        let body = frm.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.innerHTML = str;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result

[image]

The options outside `<iframe>` show their labels as expected, but those inside  only show their text contents.

Comment: That is strange. What do you see when you inspect the body of the iFrame?

Comment: @mplungjan Inspecting shows that it's the same HTML as the outside `<select>` tag, with labels intact.

Comment: And if you load the actual html page into the iframe?

Comment: @mplungjan Loading an existing HTML file into the iframe works, it only happen when the frame is populated with JS. Is it something wrong with my JS code?

Comment: Not that I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the `compatMode` property of both documents, your main document has `CSS1Compat`, but your iframe document has `BackCompat`- so it was rendered in quirks mode. And apparently in quirks mode the option `label` attribute gets ignored.

So you need to make sure that your iframe document is not in quirks mode to begin with. One way to do that, is to let a document with `<!doctype html>` load in the iframe first:

```
<select id="a">
  <option value="a" label="a">aaaaaa</option>
  <option value="b" label="b">bbbbbb</option>
  <option value="c" label="c">cccccc</option>
  <option value="d" label="d"></option>
</select>
<iframe id="frm" srcdoc="<!doctype html><html/>" onload="populateSelectField()"></iframe>
<script>
  function populateSelectField() {
    let str = document.getElementById('a').outerHTML;
    console.log(str)
    let frm = document.getElementById('frm');
    let body = frm.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.innerHTML = str;
  }
</script>
```

I am having trouble getting this to properly run inside a snippet here (something to do with iframe sandbox attributes perhaps?), but you can see that it works here, https://jsfiddle.net/58cyuhan/

Edit: Looks like even with `srcdoc=""`, it works - explicitly specifying the doctype appears not even to be necessary, perhaps it is rather the waiting for the load event of the iframe, that causes it to have a "proper" document mode(?).

Comment: Thank you, this work. But I still find it a bit weird. It need BOTH the `srcdoc` (even if just empty string) and `onload` event. Maybe it indeed has something to do with the browser preparing things.

Comment: Without any `src` or `srcdoc`, the `load` event handler will not fire to begin with.

Comment: I tried removing `srcdoc` and the event still fired, just with the buggy result. Either a bug in Chrome or JS being JS again.